# How to Print Request in Console in iPhone

Tags: iphone

i got stuck while implementing one webservice in iPhone, i think something is wrong in my Request. 
     i have tried to implement webservice using NSURLConnection & ASIHTTPRequest but didn't  get sucess.To solve the problem i want to print request as raw text which i am sending to webservice.Currently i am getting `<ASIHTTPRequest: 0x6b39fd0>`  when i print request, i want it as raw text.

Any help will be appreciated deeply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the ASIHTTPRequestConfig.h class and set the DEBUG_FORM_DATA_REQEUEST from 0 to 1.

You will see the body printed and url encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the sample code from [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) yet? Try first to run the snippets on their website, print the result using NSLog and see if it works. Then you'll know what to do with your trouble.

Comment: Thanks for you reply,
i saw the document but they dont have any info about how to print request.

suppose following is my code.

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];

now i want to see final request in nslog as raw text.
is it possible?

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting your code in the comment, in this way, other people will be able to see your code as well. Answer: no, you can't see the request as a string, it's an object, try this if it helps: NSLog(@"request: %@", [request description]);